# VStack taking more then 10 elements in it. how error is not coming

Tags: swiftui, ambiguous

I have code as below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Line 0")
            Text("Line 1")
            Text("Line 2")
            Text("Line 3")
            Text("Line 4")
            Text("Line 5")
            Text("Line 6")
            Text("Line 7")
            Text("Line 8")
            Text("Line 9")
            
            Text("Line 10")
            Text("Line 11")
            Text("Line 12")
            Text("Line 13")
            Text("Line 14")
            Text("Line 15")
            Text("Line 16")
            Text("Line 17")
            Text("Line 18")
            Text("Line 19")
            
            Text("Line 20")
            Text("Line 21")
            Text("Line 22")
            Text("Line 23")
            Text("Line 24")
            Text("Line 25")
            Text("Line 26")
            Text("Line 27")
            Text("Line 28")
            Text("Line 29")
        
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

What I know is there is limitation on the number of views it can accept as arguments. VStack can take max 10 views in it and hence `Group` is introduced.

However I am not getting any error and preview is working fine. Even app is running fine.

Why error `ambiguous reference to member 'buildBlock()’.` is not coming?

Comment: the ViewBuilder in SwiftUI 2.0 removed the 10 views restriction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ViewBuilder.buildBlock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder/buildblock(_:)-2bj1g) now takes a [type parameter pack](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0393-parameter-packs.md) (introduced in Swift 5.9) instead of 11 separate overloads, each with a different number of type parameters.

```
static func buildBlock<each Content>(_ content: repeat each Content) 
    -> TupleView<(repeat each Content)> where repeat each Content : View
```

So there is no hardcoded limit on the number of views anymore. The only limit I suppose, would be how long it takes for Swift to type-check this.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this... I see many articles saying there is limit (even SO AI search) and hence I get confused why I am not getting this error...